# What is the right way to register dependencies?-"check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, autofac

Here is my `factory` class whose responsibility is to return the `instance` based on input type.

```
public class ProcessFactory: IProcessFactory
{
    public ProcessFactory(IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest> processSalaryRequest,
                          IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest> processLeavesRequest)
    {
         _processSalaryRequest = processSalaryRequest;
         _processLeaveRequest = processLeavesRequest;
    }
}

public IProcess GetInstance(string type)
{
    Type atype;
    if (Enum.TryParse(type, out atype))
    {
        switch (atype)
        {
            case Type.Type1:
                return _processSalaryRequest ;
                break;
            case Type.Type2:
                return _processLeaveRequest ;
                break;
          }
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

This is my interface. A non-generic interface and make the generic interface inherit from it.

```
public interface IProcess
{
     void Process(string id);
}
public interface IProcess<T> : IProcess where T : class
{
}
```

Here are my registrations

```
builder.RegisterType<ProcessSalaryRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ProcessLeavesRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest>>().SingleInstance();
```

Now, here comes the challenge while registering the `factory`

```
  builder.Register(c => new ProcessFactory(c.Resolve<ProcessSalaryRequest>(),c.Resolve<ProcessLeavesRequest>())).As<IProcessFactory>().SingleInstance();
```

I am getting below error

> 'MyProject.ProcessSalaryRequest' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.'

**Updates**

Here is `ProcessSalaryRequest`

```
  public class ProcessSalaryRequest : IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>
  {
    private readonly IStatusClient _statusClient;
    public ProcessSalaryRequest(IStatusClient statusClient)
    {
        _statusClient = statusResponseClient;
    }
    void Process(string id)
    {

    }

  }
```

**Diagram of dependency**

[image]

> DependencyResolutionException: Circular component dependency detected: MyProject.Engine -> MyProject.Broker -> MyProject.ProcessControl -> MyProject.Status -> MyProject.StatusManager -> MyProject.Prcoessor-> MyProject.ProcessSalaryRequest -> MyProject.Status

Note: `Processor` gets the instance using `factory` based on some business conditions.

Comment: Please include the source code for `ProcessSalaryRequest`.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You've registered `ProcessSalaryRequest` as an interface. But not **as itself**.

Comment: how to register as itself? I am new to autofac

Comment: I suspect you meant to do `builder.Register(c => new ProcessFactory(c.Resolve<IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>>(),c.Resolve<IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest>>())).As<IProcessFactory>().SingleInstance();`

Comment: Or read up on `AsSelf`. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html

Comment: I note that you've registered `ProcessSalaryRequest`, but you're accepting `IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>`. Is there another object (i.e. ProcessSalaryRequestHandler or similar) you need to register?

Comment: No, I am now getting circular reference error :(

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve], so that we can reproduce the error. I don't see any reason for a circular reference error at the moment. Does `IStatusClient` require an `IProcessFactory`, or an `IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>`? By the way, why are you manually constructing the factory as opposed to letting Autofac do it?

Comment: sure, let me do a diagram and upload. In one of the class, based on "business logic", we need to create an instance of the dependent class. so I have used factory. if i remove the factory then I might need to inject all classes (3) where in only one of them is used based on logic.

Comment: @John updated diagram for more clarity

Comment: It looks like you will need to refactor your code so that you don't have a circular dependency. To make the issue clear: to instantiate A, you need an instance of B. To instantiate B, you need an instance of A.

Comment: @John  yes you are right. now, how do I close this question? Seems like now problem statement is changed.

Comment: I'd probably restore your question to the original problem statement, and accept Luis' answer, to be honest. You can post a question about the other problem if needs be. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided in the update, the problem seems to be when resolving the instances.

Since you registered the types this way:

```
builder.RegisterType<ProcessSalaryRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ProcessLeavesRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest>>().SingleInstance();
```

Then, you should resolve using the interface provided in the "As" section like this:

```
builder.Register(c => new ProcessFactory(c.Resolve<IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>>(),c.Resolve<IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest>>())).As<IProcessFactory>().SingleInstance();
```

In IoC libraries (or most of them) you resolve a type by the specific Interface/BaseType registered ***as*** reference.

Comment: @kudlatiger As John stated in the above comment, this is another problem (reference loop) all together and the resolving part seems to be fixed. I would suggest you to do a thorough  review of your class structure. If you just look for a work around... this technical debt will hunt you down later and will be more difficult fix. Better act now that the problem is fresh and you can identify a solution.

Comment: @kudlatiger As a quick suggestion, based on the diagram:
If the diagram you provided is correct, the reference loop could be fixed by removing the *StatusManager*'s reference from the *Status* class, and when a new status needs to be registered or save... then get a reference (maybe through injection) of *StatusManager* as a service and pass the *Status* instance being reported.

Comment: Great inputs. I am working on it. Could you suggest some better approach for replacing factory and let autofac takes care of it?

Comment: @kudlatiger You are looking for a way to change strategies when certain conditions (business rules?) are met. That would be a very lengthy explanation to post here, and I am not an autofact expert. So I will leave a very good post I found explaining how to do exactly that. Hope this could help you achieve your goal.

Here is the link: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Comment: link you shared is really helpful. great.

Answer (score 1):

Since the required interface dependencies are already registered

```
builder.RegisterType<ProcessSalaryRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessSalaryRequest>>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<ProcessLeavesRequest>().As<IProcess<ProcessLeavesRequest>>().SingleInstance();
```

then there really is no need to use the registration expression.

Just register the factory

```
builder.RegisterType<ProcessFactory>().As<IProcessFactory>().SingleInstance();
```

The container should be able to resolve the required dependencies when resolving the factory.

Provided that all other dependencies for the object graph are also pre-registered.